# Using a blender file in android

Tags: android, blender

Can I use a 3D object from Blender(.blend file) in Android? I want to move around and zoom the object in and out in my android application.

- I have found a way using it through Unity. But Unity directly builds an apk. As a result, I cannot modify the code generated by Unity in anyway. Also, Unity uses javascript/C#. How, does this sync with JAVA used in android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to render blender model in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662920/what-is-the-best-way-to-render-blender-model-in-android)

Comment: Of course you can use such a file - all you need to do is write an App that is able to render, move around, and zoom the scene. What are you having problems with?

Comment: I actually dont know how to be able to render a blender object and do other stuffs with it? Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: take a look into Unity mobile development, then learn how to model for unity using blender

Comment: Trying to do that. But unity creates an apk directly. So, I cannot modify the code generated by Unity in anyway ...

Comment: blender has so many export functionalities... depending what you will code your app with and what library you are using for 3d, you can just choose to export your file in the format you need